# Is it possible to squash all changes from a branch in TFS into one commit?

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

For personal projects I use Git for SCM, but at work we use TFS.  One thing that I like about Git is that it allows a person to easily squash all the changes made in a branch when pulling the changes back into the master branch.

The benefit of this is that if their is anything wrong with the changes they can easily be removed be reverting back to the version before the merge even if no tag was created.

Is this. or the equivalent possible in TFS?  Is this where shelving changes fits into the equation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Performing a merge in TFS results in a single commit; all of the changes from the source branch get rolled up into one changeset pended against the target branch. So as far as I understand your question, the answer is "yes".